# How much JSON should I cache in Android app?

Tags: android, caching

I'm planning to cache some JSON response strings, and I also know when they will expire (app is communicating with my web service). I want to store key-value pairs (key=URL, value={json content+expire date}) somewhere, and I think I have these options:

- store in cache folder retrieved by getCacheDir() - documentation says **you should always have a reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the amount of space you consume with cache files**
- save on a folder in SD Card (what folder? /sdcard/.temp ?) - how much is reasonable here 4 MB? 16 MB
- store in SQLite database - here I assume that 1 MB limit for internal storage is OK too, and what size is OK for SD Card?

Or should I put a combobox somewhere in app Preferences where the user will be able to choose cache location and size?

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547103/android-and-data-storage-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your JSON responses are incredibly large, I'd just store them in the internal cache, staying below 1MB as suggested.

Many Android phones ship with an included 2GB MicroSD card. I'd say you could happily go to 64MB without much issue if you choose the SD card route. I'd recommend using [`getExternalFilesDir`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) if at all possible.

Comment: well the responses are 6.5 kb in size in average, but some could be as large as 50 kb. If I *java.util.zip* -ped the JSONs, I could stuff about 4 MB worth of them into the internal storage.

Comment: Even 4MB of zipped JSON data seems a lot to me! I dare say maybe add a user preference that lets them choose how big your cache tries to keep itself - be it 1MB per Google's suggestion, or 4MB as you say. Even though each response has an expiry, you may find it preferable to let the app delete old data from your cache before the expiry date is met, in order to keep the cache small and manageable. This could be done by simply ordering all cached files by creation date, and deleting the oldest ones one-by-one until their cumulative size is beneath the specified amount.

Comment: No, with the 4 MB I meant that I can pack 4 MB worth of JSON with GZIP into 1 MB of internal storage. The cache would be rotating as you say, with deleting oldest (by access) entries to honor the limit.